# Contextual Month-over-Month Change

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Need to use DAX to show in a bar chart month-over-month change in values but need to NOT show current month or the first month

**Data:**

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| **May** | 1 |
| **Jun** | 2 |
| **Jul** | 5 |
| **Aug** | 2 |
| **Sep** | 1 |

**Expected Result:**

| Date | Difference |
| --- | --- |
| **May** | null |
| **Jun** | 1 |
| **Jul** | 3 |
| **Aug** | -3 |
| **Sep** | null |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need other measure to go in the chart, because PowerBI will automatically remove the blanks which will make your requirement impossible.

So let's assume you are using `TotalValue` and `Difference`, your measures would be something like this (you might need to adjust how you calculate the previous and next month, and make sure if you have slicers to take that info into account when determining the previous and next values):

```
TotalValue = SUM(table[value])

Difference =
  VAR currentDate = SELECTEDVALUE(table[Date])
  
  VAR currValue = [TotalValue]
  VAR prevValue = CALCULATE([TotalValue], 
                ALLSELECTED(table[Date]), 
                table[Date] = EDATE(currentDate, -1)
  VAR nextValue = CALCULATE([TotalValue], 
                ALLSELECTED(table[Date]), 
                table[Date] = EDATE(currentDate, +1)

  RETURN IF(ISBLANK(nextValue) || ISBLANK(prevValue), BLANK(), 
      currValue - prevValue)
```